# change the "slide" in processing.js

Tags: processing.js

I'm doing a science assignment that simulates the effects of different volcanoes. The user inputs information and then taking that information, there is a display of the effects the volcano has. when I try to switch the '**slide**' from the input page to the output page using a '**next**' button, it won't work.

here is the code: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/volcano-sim/6659613043589120

as you can see, the rectangle does pop up, but the rest of the stuff from the input page doesn't go away. Please help.

(also this is not exactly processing.js. it's on a site called khan academy that uses a very close spin-off of processing.js)

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask us to debug, and I'm not even sure what you're asking. Can you please provide a [mcve] in your post itself? (That might involve starting over with an example sketch just to show us the problem without including all that extra code.) Some screenshots of exactly what's going wrong and what you expect would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a spin-off of your program.  The slides work now and I cleared out the long and confusing logic.  It's different, but if you look through it a bit you should be able to pick up what it's doing.

Hope you find it helpful. :)  If you have any trouble with any of it, just post in the Tips and Thanks there.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/total-rewrite-of-code-free-to-use/5501032388755456